# Want to see if any value in one vector matches the value in another vector

Tags: c++, vector

I am writing code for a game called Bulls & Cows. I have already solved seeing if the value of one vector (if they are in the same index) are identical. However, I am not sure how to write a for loop that will move through two vectors and see if any value in one matches the value of any other index in the other vector. I would appreciate any help. Thank you!

Comment: Please provide your *source code* attempt.

Comment: You can use [`std::find()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) to find a value in a `std::vector` (or most other containers).

Answer (score 3):

The *brute force* approach is

```
for( auto& x1 : vec1 )
    for( auto& x2 : vec2 )
        if( x1 == x2 )
            return true;
return false;
```

If both vectors are of length *n*, this performs *n*<sup>2</sup> comparisons in the not found case, and on average.

That's quadratic time, O(*n*<sup>2</sup> ), which is pretty ungood.

---

For better performance you can just put all values of one vector in a *set*. Then you can check each value of the other vector, against the set. For a `std::set` the checking of each value is log(*n*), and so checking *n* values gives you O(*n* log *n*) time. For a `std::unordered_set` the checking is essentially constant time, which reduces the whole thing to O(*n*).

There is however a problem with `std::unordered_set`, that at least with the version of g++ that I use (MinGW 5.1), its standard library implementation lacks support for hashing `enum` values, so that you'd have to supply a hash function or general hashing support to make the code portable.

So,

```
using Item = decltype(v1)::value_type;
std::set<Item> v1_values{ v1.begin(), v1.end() };
for( auto& x2 : v2 )
    if( v1_values.count( x2 ) > 0 )
        return true;
return false;
```

Disclaimer: code not even glanced at by compiler, and I'm unsure about whether the `count` is the most elegant way to check since I generally just wrap the standard library things.

---

The best thing performance-wise would be to use an *incremental approach*, e.g. to update such a set each time you add a value to `v1` or `v2`. This adds to the complexity of the code, and is not independent of what you use these vectors for. I.e. it's a more intrusive solution: you generally pay for the performance by added complexity.

Answer (score 1):

This is the definition of [std::find_first_of](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find_first_of).

Answer (score 0):

Just do a simple loop:

```
vector<int> v1, v2;
//Initialize v1 and v2...

for (auto& i: v1) //Loop through each element of v1
    for (auto& j: v2) //Same for v2
        if (i == j) 
             std::cout << "Ok! They match!" << std::endl;
```

Comment: It should be mentioned that this is only for c++ 11. Else the auto should be the actual type.